# Polymorphic methods in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, overloading

In Java you can put in multiple constructors to a class that are called depending on the types and/or number of parameters that are used when an instance is constructed. 
I assume that there is the equivalent in Objective C.

Can I have a polymorphic method?

I would like to build a method that acts slightly differently according to whether a string is passed or a double?

Does that sound bonkers or is it easy?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're thinking of overloaded methods. Due to the way dynamic dispatch is implemented in Objective-C, it isn't currently possible to pass two unrelated types as arguments to the same (or same-named) method and have it understand.

In Objective-C, there are two related but distinct approaches to handling multiple kinds of input. Let's use your example of a string or a double as possible inputs. In Java, you might have:

```
 void applyWidget(String s);
 void applyWidget(double d);
```

And that's great, but not Objective-C. In Objective-C, you instead would use two different method names:

```
- (void)applyWidgetWithName: (NSString *)name;
- (void)applyWidgetWithValue: (double)value;
```

The same logic is in each method as in the Java version, but the distinct names let the compiler treat them as distinct methods (which they are, even in Java.) The code also becomes self-documenting: by reading it, you get an idea of what's happening even without comments. Alternatively, if you simply *must* have one method name, you change the parameter type to `id` and accept any object:

```
- (void)applyWidget: (id)widget;
```

Then pass either an `NSString` or an `NSNumber` wrapping your `double`. Then, in the implementation of the method, use Objective-C's introspection methods to determine how to proceed:

```
if ([widget isKindOfClass: [NSString class]]) {
    ...
} else if ([widget isKindOfClass: [NSNumber class]]) {
    double d = [widget doubleValue];
    ...
}
```

This approach essentially tells callers "send anything--I'll handle it appropriately." It can be difficult to determine the behaviour of such a method without extensive documentation.

Comment: FYI I used introspection in my view to see what kind of thing the user had typed and called an appropriate method in my model. Not too sure if that is good design\(?)\

Comment: The user would always type a string, given that that's what keyboards generally produce. What did you mean? :)

Comment: Introspection based specification is uncommon and oft indicative of a fragile architecture that should be revisited.

Comment: @bbum: Agreed, which is why I led with the other (better) approach.

Answer (score 2):

Absolutely easy:

```
- (id)initWithSomeObject:(id)object
{
    if ([object isKindOfClass:[ClassOne class]) {
        // do something
    } else if ([object isKindOfClass:[ClassTwo class]) {
        // do something else
    } // etc.
    return self;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. You are correct, it is easy once you know how. Unless you sprang from the womb with this knowledge already programmed in of course.

Comment: Easy, yes, but generally bad design.  In general, if you are taking generic arguments and then switching on the type to determine more specific behavior, it is an indication of a fragile architecture.   Not always, but most of the time.

Comment: @bbum I didn't write it's good design - it's important to mention that, but the lots-of-init-methods-for-different-objects approach doesn't technically answer OP's question.

Answer (score 1):

yes, but objc does not have proper overloading.

so you see things like `initWithDouble:`, `initWithBool:` and so on. that's part of the reason it's a bit 'wordy' for some people's taste.

to use your example:

```
@interface MONClass

- (id)initWithString:(NSString *)pString;
- (id)initWithDouble:(double)pDouble;
...
```

but the following is an error:

```
- (id)initWith:(NSString *)pString;
- (id)initWith:(double)pDouble;
```

because the selector is the same -- the parameter/return types are omitted from the selector.

Comment: @nerak99 well, you should add my advice to your bag of tricks. it will come in handy. creating object-only parameters when a builtin c type will suffice can require a lot of unnecessary allocations and add runtime lookups. as well, you erase type safety, which makes it error prone and more difficult to maintain and test, when the compiler is good at validating parameters match.

Answer (score 1):

Basically Objective C does't have proper method overloading. It will support overriding only.
Suppose if you write functions like in same class,

- (void) showMethod;
- (void) showMethod:(int) aNumber;

This will support in Objective C.
Suppose if you write functions like,

- (void) showMethod:(NSString*) aString;
- (void) showMethod:(int) aNumber;

In this way the compiler gives Error because there conflicting parameter types in implementation of showMethod.